# Find basis of $ker f*$ and $im f*$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have such information: $f: \mathbb R^{4} \rightarrow \mathbb R^{3}$, matrix $M(f)^{B}_{A}$ and I know vectors in basis $A$ and $B$.Do I think that I have to set $M(f*)^{A*}_{B*}=M(f)^{B}_{A}$and then set $M(f*)^{st}_{st}$ now? After I can read basis?